# Integrating Firebase inside a framework with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebaseui

I'm trying to include Firebase inside a framework target thats linked to an Application. When I just include Firebase to the framework target, it wont compile the App and when I include Firebase to both App and the framework, I'm seeing the following warnings.

```
objc[25463]: Class FIRAAppEnvironmentUtil is implemented in both /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-bldxbgfroizmdggroxupwpsxowvt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppUIKit.framework/AppUIKit (0x109078e98) and /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-bldxbgfroizmdggroxupwpsxowvt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppKit.framework/AppKit (0x108effdb8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Following is my Pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.6'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 3.6'

target 'AppKit' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

  target 'AppKitTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'AppUIKit' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for AppUIKit

  target 'AppUIKitTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'TestApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestApp

  target 'TestAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: We have the same problem did you found a solution Jani?